# Inserting GTM variable instead of HTML object

Tags: javascript, html, tags, google-tag-manager

I'm trying to implement a marketing tag on a website where the value needed on the tag should come from an HTML object, although when trying to replace this with a GTM variable, no data is transferred into the tag.

These are the instructions from their documentation:

> For Google Tag Manager (GTM) integration, create a HTML-object (jQuery
>   is required) containing  and replace all variables with their real
>   DATA values (cf. next section).

**`HTML-Object at your checkout page`**

```
<div id='transactionString' data-transaction-string='DATA'></div>
```

> Create a custom HTML-Tag in GTM with the following code snippet and
>   pass the data from the new HTML object. Finally, you can add your
>   checkout page to the trigger rules of GTM.

**`Create custom HTML tag in GTM`**

```
<script src="https://tracking.crealytics.com/lib/multi_conversion.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> var transactionString =  
$("#transactionString").data("transaction-string");
__multi_conversion_tracking(70, "transactionString"); 
</script> <noscript> <div style="display:inline;"> 
<img> src="https://tracking.crealytics.com/70/multi_check.php?data=transactionString">
</div> </noscript>
```

Everything is ready in the dataLayer, the formatting and the values are all correct, but the only problem is when I pass these values into the variable of GTM.

This is the custom HTML tag I set in GTM:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> var transactionString =  
$({{VariableInGTM}}).data("transaction-string");
__multi_conversion_tracking(70, "transactionString"); 
</script> <noscript> <div style="display:inline;"> 
<img> src="https://tracking.crealytics.com/70/multi_check.php?data=transactionString">
</div> </noscript>
```

So in short, I replaced

> "#transactionString"

for

> {{VariableInGTM}}

EDIT:

```
 var divElement = document.createElement("Div");  
 divElement.id = "transactionString"; 
 divElement.setAttribute('data-transaction-string', products_info);
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging using GTM's Preview mode to ensure that your variable is being populated?

Comment: Yes, th variable is being correctly populated in the data layer.

Comment: Yes, but is it also being correctly populated in GTM? GTM's variables are distinct from Data Layer variables, and you have to set up Data Layer variables in GTM to use that data in tags.

Comment: Yes, the problem is I think at the time of the function multi_conversion, I edited the question adding a Div user support gave me for adding the variable as a div instead of a normal variable.